# window.onload method, how to call multiple functions

Tags: javascript, forms

Writing some JavaScript so the form does not submit in less the fields have been filled out, and if the user has not, a message pops up saying 'please fill out the name field' or 'please fill out the email field' etc. I am writing a separate function for each field (don't know if that is the right way) and when I add each function to the window.onload, it only pops up with one of the messages. Any advice would be great.

HTML

```
 <form id="frmContact" name="frmContact" method="post" action="thanks.htm">
    <fieldset id="quickSupport">
      <legend><strong>Quick Support</strong></legend>
      <p> If your request isn't urgent, drop us a quick line and we'll get back to you within 24 hours </p>
      <p>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" value="Your Name" name="name" id="name" tabindex="10" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="text" value="Your Email" name="email" id="email" tabindex="20" />
      </p>
        <label for="comments">Comments </label>
        <br />
        <textarea name="comments" value="Message" id="comments" cols="45" rows="5" tabindex="60" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">Message</textarea>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send" tabindex="70" />
      </p>
    </fieldset>
  </form>

   <p><span id="errorMessage"></span></p>
   <p><span id="errorMessage1"></span></p>
```

JavaScript

```
function prepareEventHandlers () {
document.getElementById("frmContact").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {

        // Show message
        if (document.getElementById("email").value == "Your Email") {
            document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "Please provide at least an email address!";
            // to STOP the form from submitting
            return false;
        } else {
            // reset and allow the form to submit
            document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "";
            return true;
        }

        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent form from submitting
    }
});
}

function prepareEventHandlersName () {
document.getElementById("frmContact").addEventListener("submit",         function(event) {

        // Show message
        if (document.getElementById("name").value == "Your Name") {
            document.getElementById("errorMessage1").innerHTML = "Please provide a name!";
            // to STOP the form from submitting
            return false;
        } else {
            // reset and allow the form to submit
            document.getElementById("errorMessage1").innerHTML = "";
            return true;
        }

        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent form from submitting
    }
});
}


function start() {
prepareEventHandlers();
prepareEventHandlersName();
}
```

window.onload = start;

Comment: Use the built-in browser validation. Check the `required` attribute for input fields.

Comment: This way, you are discarding the first function attached to the event onsubmit of frmContact. Instead, define a function that does all the required checks and attach that function (only one) to the event above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the browser's built-in validation attributes.

```
<form id="frmContact" name="frmContact" method="post" action="thanks.htm">
    <fieldset id="quickSupport">
        <legend><strong>Quick Support</strong></legend>
        <p>If your request isn't urgent, drop us a quick line and we'll 
            get back to you within 24 hours</p>
        <p>
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" value="Your Name" name="name" id="name" 
                tabindex="10" required />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="text" value="Your Email" name="email" id="email" 
                tabindex="20" required />
        </p>
        <label for="comments">Comments</label>
        <br />
        <textarea name="comments" value="Message" id="comments" cols="45" 
            rows="5" tabindex="60" 
            placeholder="PLACEHOLDER WHEN NO MESSAGE IS WRITTEN" required>Message</textarea>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send" 
                tabindex="70" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

When you try to submit the form, the browser will automatically display nice error messages for you, in the user's language. No JavaScript required.

---

The reason your code is failing, because

```
document.getElementById("frmContact").onsubmit = ...
```

will override any previous `onsubmit` handler you've added.

You need to use **[`.addEventListener()`](https://devdocs.io/dom/eventtarget/addeventlistener)** instead, if you want to add multiple functions.

A more correct way would be to create a single function that does all checks, and attach that as the handler, once.

Comment: did not know about required. Thank you!! Have to say though, I am new to JavaScript and I am not going to lie, that doesn't make much sense with the.addEventListener..... so write that line of code, then add both function to it???

Comment: Think about it this way, with `something.onsubmit = something`, you're overriding a variable with a new value each time. With `something.addEventListener('submit', something)`, you're adding a new event listener to the list of event listeners.

Comment: I have swapped the .onsubmit, for the addEventListener and when I click submit, it takes me to the local page, rather than displaying the messages. I am feeling slightly stupid here. Should the code look something like this??


    function prepareEventHandlers() { 
    document.getElementById("frmContact").addEventListener("submit", function {

Answer (score 0):

Both functions are running, but you're overwriting the `onsubmit` handler for `frmContact` in your second function.  To avoid this, don't assign event handlers that way.  Instead, use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FEventTarget.addEventListener).

```
document.getElementById("frmContact").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    if (document.getElementById("email").value == "Your Email") {
        // Show message
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent form from submitting
    }
});
```

Note that when you do it this way, you can't prevent the form from submitting by simply returning false.  Instead, you have to use the event's [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) method.

Comment: I'm sorry mate but I have been trying to implement your line of code but it doesn't seem to be working. Would you be kind enough to show me what you meant? I am a bit of a newbie when it comes to JavaScript. Sorry to be a pain

Comment: @Patrick What's not working?  Is the form still submitting?  Or is there a JavaScript error in your console?

Comment: no errors coming up and its submitting and directing me to the local page

Comment: Might as well give up now. Still not working mate. Ill put up what I have changed to see if you can work out where I am going wrong?